# How to you make a character return on each character in a word?

Tags: java, for-loop, char, cpu-word

Such as if you type happy it will display

h

a

p

p

y

Right now I have this:

```
    public static void three(){

    String x = keyb.next();

         int  y= x.length();

    char []  word = new char [y];

        System.out.println("It has " + y);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

which just makes the word appear how many characters it is. but i just want to make each character itself indent. please and thank you!

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Oh sorry i am in java. I dont know if there are different forms of java. Thanks for answering so fast :D

Answer (score 2):

As simple as this:

```
String str = "happy";
for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++){
    System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: really? okay thanks i will definitely try it out. I am just starting to program!